# ZF models correct use

Tags: zend-framework, model

I am struggling with how to understand the correct usage of models. Currently i use the inheritance of Db_Table directly and declare all the business logic there. I know it's not correct way to do this.

One solution would be to use Doctrine ORM, but this requires learning curve and all the current components what i use needs to be rewritten paginator and auth. Also Doctrine1 adds a another dozen classes which need to be loaded.

So the current cleanest implementation what i have seen is to use the Data Mapper classes between the so called model and DbTabel. I haven't yet implemented this as it seems to head writing another ORM. But example could be something this: SQL table User

- create class with setters, getters, business logic here */model/User.php*
- data mapper */model/mapper/UserMapper.php*, the funcionality is basically writing all the update, save actions in here.
- the data source */model/DbTable/User.php* extends the Db_Table_Abstract

Problems are with relationships between other models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it beneficial to **not** have my models extend Db_Table, but to use composition instead. That means my model 'has a' Db_Table rather than 'is a' Db_Table.

That way I find it much easier to reference multiple tables in the same model, which is a common requirement. This is enough for a simple project. I am currently developing a more complex application and have used the Data Mapper pattern and have found that it has simplified my code more than I would have believed.

Specifically, I have created a class which provides all access to the database and exposes methods such as getUser() etc.. That way, if the DB changes, or my client wants something daft like storing records in XML or we split the servers or something I only have to rewrite one class.

Again, my models do not extend this class, but have an instance of it assigned as a property during construction.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the 'correct' way depends on the situation.  Following the YAGNI and KISS principles, it is not good to over-complicate your model setup unless you really believe that it will benefit you in the long run.

What is the application you are developing?  How is your current setup of extending `Db_Table` holding you back?

Comment: You are correct, application what i develop is similar to blog or cms. The posts has the comments, users, tags. The main thing is that i want to make the components modular as possible (users, news, blog, poll) and also i have to adopt the TDD in project that's why i need to make modules a bit loose coupled.